# How to disable a notification with rxandroidble?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ble, rxandroidble

I'm currently trying to use rxandroidble in order to replace the native BLE API of Android of one of our app.

How to disable a notification? I'm able to enable it with the sample code, this one:

```
device.establishConnection(context, false)
.flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.setupNotification(characteristicUuid)) 
.doOnNext(notificationObservable -> { // OK }) 
.flatMap(notificationObservable -> notificationObservable)     
.subscribe(bytes -> { // OK });
```

But in my product I have a use case where I have to disable / enable the notification(s) on demand.

Plus, I tried to directly unsubscribe / reconnect instead of disable / enable the notification but the unsubscribe command is never executed apparently, my hypothesis is because I have a high throughput (my device notifies at 300 - 400Hz), is it plausible?

(I know that BLE is not the most appropriate technology for high throughput but it's for R&D purpose here :) )

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling notifications happens whenever the `Observable` from `RxBleConnection.setupNotification()` will be subscribed. To disable the notification one must unsubscribe from the above subscription.

There are several ways in which it can be coded. One of them is:

```
    final RxBleDevice rxBleDevice = // your RxBleDevice
    final Observable<RxBleConnection> sharedConnectionObservable = rxBleDevice.establishConnection(this, false).share();

    final Observable<Boolean> firstNotificationStateObservable = // an observable that will emit true when notification should be enabled and false when disabled
    final UUID firstNotificationUuid = // first of the needed UUIDs to enable / disable
    final Subscription subscription = firstNotificationStateObservable
            .distinctUntilChanged() // to be sure that we won't get more than one enable commands
            .filter(enabled -> enabled) // whenever it will emit true
            .flatMap(enabled -> sharedConnectionObservable // we take the shared connection
                    .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.setupNotification(firstNotificationUuid)) // enable the notification
                    .flatMap(notificationObservable -> notificationObservable) // and take the bytes
                    .takeUntil(firstNotificationStateObservable.filter(enabled1 -> !enabled1)) // and we are subscribing to this Observable until we want to disable - note that only the observable from sharedConnectionObservable will be unsubscribed
            )
            .subscribe(
                    notificationBytes -> { /* handle the bytes */ },
                    throwable -> { /* handle exception */ }
            );
```

Note that in the above example the connection will be closed whenever the last subscription to `sharedConnectionObservable` will end.

To enable / disable different characteristics you can copy and paste the above code with different `Observable<Boolean>` as enable / disable inputs and different `UUID`'s.

Comment: Instead of `Subscription subscription` it will be `Disposable disposable`  for `RxJava2`. However, for `firstNotificationStateObservable ` i tried `Observable.just(true)` but the code suggested above is doing nothing.

Comment: How do you share the connection `sharedConnectionObservable =  bleDevice .establishConnection(false).share(); ` ? because until we don't subscribe it will not actually perform the connection operation how do you suggest to use `establishConenction` in above code

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin

In kotlin, Use dispose() to disable the notification.

```
#ENABLE NOTIFICATION
val result = device.establishConnection(false)
.flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.setupNotification(characteristicUuid))
.doOnNext(notificationObservable -> {
    // Notification has been set up
})
.flatMap(notificationObservable -> notificationObservable) // <-- Notification has been set up, now observe value changes.
.subscribe(
    bytes -> {
        // Given characteristic has been changes, here is the value.
    },
    throwable -> {
        // Handle an error here.
    }
);


#DISABLE NOTIFICATION
result.dispose()
```

Tried to unsubscribe but it didn't work, still not sure which one is best dispose() or unsubscribe()