# How to enable/disable to notification/indication in RxAndroidBLE

Tags: android, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I am creating a `RxJava2` chain where in I want to enable and disable notification. the flow I am setting is as follows.

1. establish a connection.
2. set the notification to `READ_STATUS UUID`.
3. if the returned byte is `zero` then perform a write byte `01` to `WRITE_STATUS UUID` and after `WRITE_STATUS`, enable the notification of `READ_STATUS UUID` to verify it has byte value `1`.
4. else if the returned byte is `1` then just enable other indicators (`UUID1`, `UUID2`,`UUD3`)  and read the value.

I have a problem at step 2 and 3 where I am reading the value of `READ_STATUS UUID` by enabling the notification. in order to re-read the value, I probably need to disable the notification and then again enable it. And to disable to the notification I have to dispose that particular `setupNotification` .

Code is as follows

```
  connectDisposable=

                    device.establishConnection(false)

                   .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> {

                       rxBleConnection.discoverServices();
                       mRxBleConnection = rxBleConnection;
                       return Observable.just(rxBleConnection);
                   })
                   .flatMap(rxBleConnection ->mRxBleConnection.setupNotification(READ_STATUS,NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(it->it))
                   .takeUntil(bytes -> { 
                        
                        if(getByteValue(bytes)==0)
                            return false;// dispose above to disable the notification
                        else
                            return true; // no need to disable the notification and continue writing
                    })
                            

                     .flatMap(bytes -> {

                        return Observable.zip(

                                mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(WRITE_STATUS, new byte[]{1}).toObservable(),
                                // setupNotification again to check whether read status has 1 or not 
                                mRxBleConnection.setupNotification(READ_STATUS, NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(it->it),
                                Pair::new

                        );
                    })
                     .flatMap(bytes ->{

                        byte [] val= bytes.first;
                        if(getByteValue(val) == 1){

                            return Observable.zip(
                                    mRxBleConnection.setupIndication(HISTORY, NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).doOnNext(observable -> Log.e(TAG,"Here 1 ")).flatMap(it -> it),
                                    mRxBleConnection.setupIndication(PARAMCHECK, NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).doOnNext(observable -> Log.e(TAG,"Here 2 ")).flatMap(it -> it),
                                    mRxBleConnection.setupIndication(FAULTINFO, NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).doOnNext(observable -> Log.e(TAG,"Here 3 ")).flatMap(it -> it),
                                  
                                    Data::Readings);
                        }
                       
                        return Observable.empty();
                    }).subscribe(data -> {
                    
                    });
```

The problem with this code is my `takeUntil` is firing at the last it does not dispose the previous `setupNotificaion` operation so that I can re read it later.

I tried solution mentioned over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485301/how-to-disable-a-notification-with-rxandroidble) thread but unfortunately I am not sharing the `RxBleConnection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem with this code is my takeUntil is firing at the last it does not dispose the previous setupNotificaion operation so that I can re read it later.

The problem is that your condition is inverted. From `.takeUntil()` Javadoc:

> ```
>  * @return an Observable that first emits items emitted by the source Observable, checks the specified
>  *         condition after each item, and then completes when the condition is satisfied.
> ```

You have used:

```
                   .takeUntil(bytes -> { 
                        
                        if(getByteValue(bytes)==0)
                            return false;// dispose above to disable the notification
                        else
                            return true; // no need to disable the notification and continue writing
                    })
```

where it should be satisfied (return true) when the upstream should get disposed:

```
                   .takeUntil(bytes -> { 
                        
                        if(getByteValue(bytes)==0)
                            return true;// dispose above to disable the notification
                        else
                            return false; // no need to disable the notification and continue writing
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

To unsubscribe or to dispose `setupNotification` or `setupIndication` one can use the following code. I am sure there could be different ways but so far I could find this

```
private Observable<Pair<byte[],byte[]>> getValueFromIndication(RxBleConnection rxBleConnection){

         final PublishSubject<Boolean> unsubscribeOperation= PublishSubject.create();


        return Observable.zip(

                rxBleConnection.setupIndication(TSDictionary.FAULT_RETRY_COUNT_SEQUENCE,NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(it->it).takeUntil(unsubscribeOperation),
                rxBleConnection.setupIndication(TSDictionary.FAULT_RETRY_INFORMATION,NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(it->it).takeUntil(unsubscribeOperation),

                (bytes, bytes2) -> {

                    unsubscribeOperation.onNext(true);

                    return Pair.create(bytes,bytes2);
                }
        );
}
```

In above code, I am zipping two indication operations and once I get the value from it I am unsubscribing from the change chain using `PublishSubject` and `takeUntil`.